# Jquery Tablesorter filter and external select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, tablesorter, jquery-filter

I'm using tablesorter and the filter widget. I found this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LYyvp/15/) that allows filtering entries with a select box (Filter by age). I want to add that select box to [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/6sPC3/1/), but it doesn't work when simply adding

```
 $(".selectAge").bind('change', function (e) {
     var cols=[]
     cols[3] = $(this).val()
    $('table').trigger('search', [cols]);
 });
```

to my example code. Would you please tell me how to get the select box to work?

My example code is a copy from the [official example](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was working, it just didn't look like it. The one problem with the select is that the "reset" option needed an empty string as a value:

```
<select class="selectAge tablesorter-filter" data-column="3">
    <option class="reset" value="">Filter by age</option>
    <option>&gt;=25</option>
    <option>&lt;=25</option>
</select>
```

[Here is an updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/LYyvp/17/) (all I changed was the select and added the blue theme css).

---

Update: Just so you know, in the next update, you can just give that `select` a `"search"` class name like the other input, and be sure to include a `data-column="#"` attribute, and have it work automatically when you use `bindSearch`, so there would not be a need to add extra code:

```
$.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch( $('#mytable'), $('.search') );
```